# Representing a set with gluing conditions

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to represent projective elliptic curve addition in Isabelle:

```
function proj_add :: "(real × real) × bit ⇒ (real × real) × bit ⇒ (real × real) × bit" where
  "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), l+j)" 
    if "delta x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
| "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), l+j)" 
if "delta' x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
```

so far, I was taught how to do conditional definition and suggested to use the bit type for values in {0,1}. Here is a third representation problem. Assume the following definitions:

```
 definition "e_aff = {(x,y). e' x y = 0}" 
 definition "e_circ = {(x,y). x ≠ 0 ∧ y ≠ 0 ∧ (x,y) ∈ e_aff}"
```

A projective elliptic curve is defined by (see pages 12, 13 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05278.pdf) for the original):

> taking two copies of e_aff glued along e_circ with isomorphism τ. We write (P,i) ∈ E with i ∈ {0,1} for the image of P ∈ e_aff in E using th ith copy of e_aff. The gluing condition gives for P ∈ e_circ, (P,i)
>   = (τ P,i+1)

How should I represent this set in Isabelle? My idea is that this should be a quotient set with equivalence classes made of one or two elements. But then how do i restrict the above function to work on these equivalence classes?

**Edit**

The equivalence relation is obtained by composing this relation with an or condition making it reflexive.

Comment: There exists some infrastructure in place for dealing with set-theoretic quotients in Isabelle. However, I have only used it minimally in the context of the declaration of quotient types using quotient_type and transferring the results between the original type and the quotient type (which can be semi-automated using transfer). Apparently, there was a conference paper about the best practices of using quotient constructions using set-theoretic framework of Isabelle: `L. C. Paulson. Defining functions on equivalence classes. ACM Trans. on Computational Logic 7 4 (2006), 658–675.`

Comment: Depending on the approach that you decide to take, some of the relevant infrastructure can be found in the theories: `Relation.thy`, `Equiv_Relations.thy`, `Quotient.thy` and `Lifting.thy`.

Comment: @xanonec your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the approach I followed:

```
definition "proj_add_class c1 c2 =
  (((case_prod (λ x y. the (proj_add x y))) ` 
   (Map.dom (case_prod proj_add) ∩ (c1 × c2))) 
   // gluing)"

definition "proj_addition c1 c2 = the_elem(proj_add_class c1 c2)"
```

where I follow the answer to [Gather all non-undefined values after addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186678/gather-all-non-undefined-values-after-addition).