# Gather all non-undefined values after addition

Tags: isabelle

I have the following addition in Isabelle:

```
function proj_add :: "(real × real) × bit ⇒ (real × real) × bit ⇒ (real × real) × bit" where
  "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), l+j)" 
    if "delta x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 ∧ (x1,y1) ∈ e_aff ∧ (x2,y2) ∈ e_aff"
| "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = ((ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)), l+j)" 
    if "delta' x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 ∧ (x1,y1) ∈ e_aff ∧ (x2,y2) ∈ e_aff"
| "proj_add ((x1,y1),l) ((x2,y2),j) = undefined"
    if "delta x1 y1 x2 y2 = 0 ∧ delta' x1 y1 x2 y2 = 0 ∨ (x1,y1) ∉ e_aff ∨ (x2,y2) ∉ e_aff"
  apply(fast,fastforce)
  using coherence e_aff_def by auto
```

Now, I want to extract all defined values to simulate addition on classes instead of specific values:

```
function proj_add_class :: "((real × real) × bit) set ⇒ ((real × real) × bit) set ⇒ ((real × real) × bit) set"  where
"proj_add_class c1 c2 = 
  (⋃ cr ∈ c1 × c2.  proj_add cr.fst cr.snd)"
```

The above is just a template. Apparently, I cannot take the first element from cr and thus I'm getting an error. On the other hand, how can I remove undefined values?

See [here](https://github.com/rjraya/Isabelle/blob/master/curves/Hales.thy) for the complete theory.

Comment: @xanonec that is a nice solution. However, does it eliminate undefined values?

Comment: @xanonec i guess i can just filter the resulting list

Comment: You mean this won't work also? definition proj_add_class  where 
"proj_add_class c1 c2 = 
  Set.filter (λ x. x = undefined) ((case_prod proj_add) ` (c1 × c2))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

Having gained a certain level of understanding of the article upon which the formalisation is based, I decided to update the answer. The original answer is available through the revision history: I believe that everything that was stated in the original answer is sensible, but, possibly, less optimal from the perspective of the style of exposition than the revised answer.

---

**Introduction**

I use a slightly updated notation based on my own revision of a part of a draft of your formalisation associated with 4033cbf288. The following theories have been imported: `Complex_Main` `"HOL-Algebra.Group"` `"HOL-Algebra.Bij"` and `"HOL-Library.Bit"`

---

**Definitions I**

First, I restate some of the relevant definitions to ensure that the answer is self-contained:

```
locale curve_addition =
  fixes c d :: real
begin

definition e :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real" 
  where "e x y = x⇧2 + c*y⇧2 - 1 - d*x⇧2*y⇧2"

fun add :: "real × real ⇒ real × real ⇒ real × real" (infix ‹⊕⇩E› 65) 
  where
    "(x1, y1) ⊕⇩E (x2, y2) =
      (
        (x1*x2 - c*y1*y2) div (1 - d*x1*y1*x2*y2), 
        (x1*y2 + y1*x2) div (1 + d*x1*y1*x2*y2)
      )"

definition delta_plus :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩y›) 
  where "δ⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2 = 1 + d*x1*y1*x2*y2"

definition delta_minus :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩x›) 
  where "δ⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2 = 1 - d*x1*y1*x2*y2"

definition delta :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩E›) 
  where "δ⇩E x1 y1 x2 y2 = (δ⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2) * (δ⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2)"

end

locale ext_curve_addition = curve_addition +
  fixes c' d' t
  assumes c'_eq_1[simp]: "c' = 1"
  assumes d'_neq_0[simp]: "d' ≠ 0"
  assumes c_def: "c = c'⇧2"
  assumes d_def: "d = d'⇧2"
  assumes t_sq_def: "t⇧2 = d/c"
  assumes t_sq_n1: "t⇧2 ≠ 1"
begin

fun add0 :: "real × real ⇒ real × real ⇒ real × real" (infix ‹⊕⇩0› 65) 
  where "(x1, y1) ⊕⇩0 (x2, y2) = (x1, y1/sqrt(c)) ⊕⇩E (x2, y2/sqrt(c))"

definition delta_plus_0 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩0⇩y›) 
  where "δ⇩0⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2 = δ⇩y x1 (y1/sqrt(c)) x2 (y2/sqrt(c))"

definition delta_minus_0 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩0⇩x›)
  where "δ⇩0⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2 = δ⇩x x1 (y1/sqrt(c)) x2 (y2/sqrt(c))"

definition delta_0 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩0›) 
  where "δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 = (δ⇩0⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2) * (δ⇩0⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2)"

definition delta_plus_1 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩1⇩y›) 
  where "δ⇩1⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2 = x1*x2 + y1*y2"

definition delta_minus_1 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩1⇩x›) 
  where "δ⇩1⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2 = x2*y1 - x1*y2"

definition delta_1 :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real ⇒ real" (‹δ⇩1›) 
  where "δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 = (δ⇩1⇩x x1 y1 x2 y2) * (δ⇩1⇩y x1 y1 x2 y2)"

fun ρ :: "real × real ⇒ real × real" 
  where "ρ (x, y) = (-y, x)"
fun τ :: "real × real ⇒ real × real" 
  where "τ (x, y) = (1/(t*x), 1/(t*y))"

fun add1 :: "real × real ⇒ real × real ⇒ real × real" (infix ‹⊕⇩1› 65) 
  where 
    "(x1, y1) ⊕⇩1 (x2, y2) = 
      (
        (x1*y1 - x2*y2) div (x2*y1 - x1*y2), 
        (x1*y1 + x2*y2) div (x1*x2 + y1*y2)
      )"

definition e' :: "real ⇒ real ⇒ real" 
  where "e' x y = x⇧2 + y⇧2 - 1 - t⇧2*x⇧2*y⇧2"

end

locale projective_curve = ext_curve_addition
begin

definition "E⇩a⇩f⇩f = {(x, y). e' x y = 0}"

definition "E⇩O = {(x, y). x ≠ 0 ∧ y ≠ 0 ∧ (x, y) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f}"

definition G where
  "G ≡ {id, ρ, ρ ∘ ρ, ρ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ, τ, τ ∘ ρ, τ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ, τ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ}"

definition symmetries where 
  "symmetries = {τ, τ ∘ ρ, τ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ, τ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ}"

definition rotations where
  "rotations = {id, ρ, ρ ∘ ρ, ρ ∘ ρ ∘ ρ}"

definition E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 where
  "E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 = 
    {
      ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)).
        (x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 
    }"

definition E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1 where
  "E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1 = 
    {
      ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)). 
        (x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 
    }"

end
```

---

**Definitions II**

I use `coherence` without proof, but I have ported the proof in the repository to my notation before copying the statement of the theorem to this answer, i.e. the proof does exist but it is not part of the answer.

```
context projective_curve
begin

type_synonym repEPCT = ‹((real × real) × bit)›

type_synonym EPCT = ‹repEPCT set›

definition gluing :: "(repEPCT × repEPCT) set" 
  where
  "gluing = 
    {
      (((x0, y0), l), ((x1, y1), j)). 
        ((x0, y0) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f) ∧
        (
          ((x0, y0) ∈ E⇩O ∧ (x1, y1) = τ (x0, y0) ∧ j = l + 1) ∨
          (x0 = x1 ∧ y0 = y1 ∧ l = j)
        )
    }"

definition E where "E = (E⇩a⇩f⇩f × UNIV) // gluing"

lemma coherence:
  assumes "δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0" "δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0" 
  assumes "e' x1 y1 = 0" "e' x2 y2 = 0"
  shows "(x1, y1) ⊕⇩1 (x2, y2) = (x1, y1) ⊕⇩0 (x2, y2)"
  sorry

end
```

---

**proj_add**

The definition of `proj_add` is almost identical to the one in the original question with the exception of the added option `domintros` (it is hardly possible to state anything meaningful about it without the domain theorems). I also show that it is equivalent to the plain definition that is currently used.

```
context projective_curve
begin

function (domintros) proj_add :: "repEPCT ⇒ repEPCT ⇒ repEPCT" 
  (infix ‹⊙› 65) 
  where 
    "((x1, y1), i) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) = ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩0 (x2, y2), i + j)"
      if "(x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" and "(x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" and "δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
  | "((x1, y1), i) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) = ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩1 (x2, y2), i + j)"
      if "(x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" and "(x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" and "δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0"
  | "((x1, y1), i) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) = undefined" 
      if "(x1, y1) ∉ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∨ (x2, y2) ∉ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∨ 
        (δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 = 0 ∧ δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 = 0)"
  subgoal by (metis τ.cases surj_pair)
  subgoal by auto
  subgoal unfolding E⇩a⇩f⇩f_def using coherence by auto
  by auto

termination proj_add using "termination" by blast

lemma proj_add_pred_undefined:
  assumes "¬ ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 ∪ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1" 
  shows "((x1, y1), l) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) = undefined"
  using assms unfolding E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0_def E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1_def
  by (auto simp: proj_add.domintros(3) proj_add.psimps(3))

lemma proj_add_def:
    "(proj_add ((x1, y1), i) ((x2, y2), j)) = 
      (
        if ((x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0)
        then ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩0 (x2, y2), i + j)
        else 
          (
            if ((x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0)   
            then ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩1 (x2, y2), i + j)
            else undefined
          )
      )"
    (is "?lhs = ?rhs")
proof(cases ‹δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 ∧ (x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f›)
  case True 
  then have True_exp: "(x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" "(x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" "δ⇩0 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0" 
    by auto
  then have rhs: "?rhs = ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩0 (x2, y2), i + j)" by simp
  show ?thesis unfolding proj_add.simps(1)[OF True_exp, of i j] rhs ..
next
  case n0: False show ?thesis
  proof(cases ‹δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0 ∧ (x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f ∧ (x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f›)
    case True show ?thesis
    proof-
      from True n0 have False_exp: 
        "(x1, y1) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" "(x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f" "δ⇩1 x1 y1 x2 y2 ≠ 0" 
        by auto
      with n0 have rhs: "?rhs = ((x1, y1) ⊕⇩1 (x2, y2), i + j)" by auto
      show ?thesis unfolding proj_add.simps(2)[OF False_exp, of i j] rhs ..
    qed
  next
    case False then show ?thesis using n0 proj_add.simps(3) by auto
  qed
qed

end
```

---

**proj_add_class**

I also provide what I would consider to be a natural solution (again, using the `function` infrastructure) for the statement of `proj_add_class` and show that it agrees with the definition that is used at the moment on the domain of interest.

```
context projective_curve
begin

function (domintros) proj_add_class :: "EPCT ⇒ EPCT ⇒ EPCT" (infix ‹⨀› 65) 
  where 
    "A ⨀ B = 
      the_elem 
        (
          {
            ((x1, y1), i) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) | x1 y1 i x2 y2 j. 
              ((x1, y1), i) ∈ A ∧ ((x2, y2), j) ∈ B ∧ 
              ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 ∪ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1
          } // gluing
        )" 
      if "A ∈ E" and "B ∈ E" 
  | "A ⨀ B = undefined" if "A ∉ E ∨ B ∉ E" 
  by (meson surj_pair) auto

termination proj_add_class using "termination" by auto

definition proj_add_class' (infix ‹⨀''› 65) where 
  "proj_add_class' c1 c2 =
    the_elem 
      (
        (case_prod (⊙) ` 
        ({(x, y). x ∈ c1 ∧ y ∈ c2 ∧ (fst x, fst y) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 ∪ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1})) // gluing
      )"

lemma proj_add_class_eq:
  assumes "A ∈ E" and "B ∈ E"
  shows "A ⨀' B = A ⨀ B"
proof-
  have 
    "(λ(x, y). x ⊙ y) ` 
      {(x, y). x ∈ A ∧ y ∈ B ∧ (fst x, fst y) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 ∪ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1} =
    {
      ((x1, y1), i) ⊙ ((x2, y2), j) | x1 y1 i x2 y2 j. 
      ((x1, y1), i) ∈ A ∧ ((x2, y2), j) ∈ B ∧ ((x1, y1), x2, y2) ∈ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩0 ∪ E⇩a⇩f⇩f⇩1
    }"
    apply (standard; standard)
    subgoal unfolding image_def by clarsimp blast
    subgoal unfolding image_def by clarsimp blast
    done  
  then show ?thesis 
    unfolding proj_add_class'_def proj_add_class.simps(1)[OF assms]
    by auto
qed

end
```

---

**Conclusion**

The appropriate choice of a definition is a subjective matter. Therefore, I can only express my personal opinion about what I believe to be the most suitable choice.

Comment: just to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid, i'm using your approach for proj_add_class but eliminating e_aff_0 u e_aff_1 condition. I think I can rewrite quite well the proof because i should have shown independence of the point (gluing_add lemmas) earlier

Comment: @Javier I doubt I will be able to look into this soon. Indeed, `proj_add_class` might be overdefined. In general, you merely need to show that the definition that you wish to use is identical to the existing one, i.e. you need to show the lemma `proj_add_class2 = proj_add_class`, where `proj_add_class2` is your own definition (obviously, you do not need to keep both definitions and this lemma in the theory after you prove it, but it is the only way to be certain that nothing else will go wrong).

Comment: In connection with your last question, I looked at your formalization very briefly and noticed that you use both `proj_add_class` and `proj_add_class'` from my answer. Obviously, the suggestion that I was trying to make was for you to use only `proj_add_class`. Of course, `proj_add_class'` could also be a suitable alternative, but I can hardly understand why you would wish to use both. My answer contains both definitions merely to demonstrate that they agree on the domain of interest. Naturally, it may be possible to simplify them further if you take into account various derived properties.

Comment: dear @xanonec, regarding your mail, thanks. I removed proj_add_class' (after all it didn't affect the proof) and also proj_add'. regarding the useof e_aff_0 union e_aff_1 in the definition of proj_add_class, as you see in the final state is still there, that's because when i rethought the problem they were necessary either because I would have to change many proofs or/and because they are algebraic conditions easy to check, I don't think is a big deal.